# error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "93.143.119.96", user "postgres", database "UMA_Metkovic", no encryption

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, unix, knex.js

I have my local database. So i made aws databse, and migrated data following this yt video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi44UHVYWEg&t=8s&pp=ygUUbG9jYWwgZGF0YWJzZSB0byBhd3M%3D

My connection which looks like this:

```
const postgres=knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host : 'database-1.cb404o0cwdlr.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    user : 'postgres',
    password : '*********',
    database : 'UMA_Metkovic',
    port: 5432,
    ssl: false, // Add this line
  }
});
```

I get error that is in title.

I tryed to change pg_hba.conf and it look like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                                       METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                                           trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32                                  trust
host    UMA_Metkovic    postgres    database-1.cb404o0cwdlr.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com                            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                                       trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                                           scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32                                  scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                                       scram-sha-256
```

In my `postgresql.conf`, I added the line `listen_addresses = '*'`

Anyone know what the problem might be? With my local address, everything is working fine.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem, your `pg_hba.conf` for the AWS Postgres instance does not have an entry for a connection from your remote client  at 93.143.119.96. Read [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for how to do the setup.

Comment: All your pg_hba 'host' lines only match the loopback address, i.e. connections coming from localhost.

Comment: As a side note, `ssl: false` is probably not a good idea in 99.99% of cases.

Comment: Did you reload the configuration after the changes in pg_hba.conf?

Comment: Yes i've reloaded pg_hba.conf.
///////////
Added :
# Allow connections from 93.143.119.96 using MD5 authentication
host    all             all             93.143.119.96/32                                md5
////////////
Still same problem. 
//////////////
When i try to connect command:
psql -h 93.143.119.96 -U postgres -d database-1 -W 
////
psql: error: connection to server at "93.143.119.96", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?



Dont know what to try anymore, going in circles.

Comment: 1) **Add  information as properly formatted text as update to question text, not in comments**. 2) That is a different error that indicates there is a firewall blocking port 5432 on the remote server.

Comment: Your new  entry in `pg_hba.conf` is incorrect. You entered the information for the location of the Postgres server, which is what users attempt a connection to. `pg_hba.conf` is for specifying addresses for where connections are originating from, in this case 93.143.119.96. That is why you had an issue with `psql -h 93.143.119.96  ...` you where trying to connect to yourself and either  there is a firewall or you don't have a Postgres server running at 93.143.119.96 .  Again I urge you to read the link I posted in my first comment.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common error when connecting to an Amazon RDS database.

In your SQL client, use `SSL=true` and it should work fine.

Comment: This is not going to help in this instance as the `pg_hba.conf` has no entries for remote connections SSL or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, Hat's off to you!